# Rails - get toggle-button status in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, togglebutton

I did long research, but cannot find solution. I want to make a list of toggle-buttons  in my form and then save ones checked by user. I know that I can named toggle-button and then find it in controller by params[:togglebutton-name], but it seems that toggle-button hasn't got any value. So for example I have 5 toggle-buttons, and user will check two of them. Then I want to know about it in Controller. What should I do?

toggle-buttons:

```
<% current_user.type_tags.each do |type_tag| %>
            <button name="type<%= type_tag.id %>" id="associated-type-tag-<%= type_tag.id %>" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
                <%= type_tag.name %>
            </button>
        <% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def create
  @try = params[:type1]
  render 'help'
end
```

Help:

```
Value: <%= @try %>;
```

And in result I have this:

```
Value: ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've already found the solution. I used btn-group with data-toggle: "buttons". Inside I have label and input with type=checkbox. That approach allows me to get a true value in my Controller if button is pressed. I can style the buttons on my own too.

I hope it will be useful for somebody.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <% current_user.type_tags.each do |type_tag| %>
                <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    <input name="type<%= type_tag.id %>" id="associated-type-tag-<%= type_tag.id %>" type="checkbox" autocomplete="off">
                        <%= type_tag.name %>
                    </input>
                </label>
            <% end %>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to understand that my switch button was missing the "name" attribute to appear in my controller!